# Add inline labels to a horizontal bar with pure SVG

Tags: svg

I use the bellow SVG code to build a horizontal bar chart. It is OK, but I need also two inline labels before and after the chart. I know how to add them with HTML and CSS, but I want to solve this only with pure SVG. How to do this?

```html
  <svg class="chart" width="300px" height="40">
        <g transform="translate(0,0)">
            <rect width="82%" height="22" fill="lightskyblue"></rect>
            <rect width="100%" height="22" style="fill:none; stroke-width:1; stroke:gray;"></rect>
            <text y="30" dx="0.25em" dy=".35em">0</text>
            <text x="20%" y="10" dy=".35em" fill="red">|</text>
            <text x="20%" y="30" dx="-0.25em" dy=".35em" fill="red">13</text>
            <text x="100%" y="30" dx="-1.25em" dy=".35em">63</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

This is what I have now:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it work I'm using your code as a nested svg inside a larger svg element. Please observe I'm using a viewBox attribute where the x component has a negative value (-50) making space for the text.

```css
svg{border:solid;}
```

```html
<svg class="chart" width="300px" viewBox="-50 0 400 40">
  <text y="20" x="-45">TXT</text>
  <text x="345" y="20" text-anchor="end">TXT</text>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 40" width="300">
        <rect width="82%" height="22" fill="lightskyblue"></rect>
        <rect width="100%" height="22" style="fill:none; stroke-width:1; stroke:gray;"></rect>
        <text y="30" dx="0.25em" dy=".35em">0</text>
        <text x="20%" y="10" dy=".35em" fill="red">|</text>
        <text x="20%" y="30" dx="-0.25em" dy=".35em" fill="red">13</text>
        <text x="100%" y="30" dx="-1.25em" dy=".35em">63</text>
  </svg>
 </svg>
```

I must tell you that I wouldn't percentages for the position and size of the rects. I would have done it using user units (without unit identifier) and I wouldn't have needed to wrap it in another svg element.

#### UPDATE

the OP is commenting

> Can you give another example, without percentages for the position and size of the rects and without wrapping it in another svg element

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg class="chart" width="300px" viewBox="-50 0 400 40">
  <text y="20" x="-45">TXT</text>
  <text x="345" y="20" text-anchor="end">TXT</text>
    
        <rect width="246" height="22" fill="lightskyblue"></rect>
        <rect width="300" height="22" style="fill:none; stroke-width:1; stroke:gray;"></rect>
        <text y="30" dx="0.25em" dy=".35em">0</text>
        <text x="60" y="10" dy=".35em" fill="red">|</text>
        <text x="60" y="30" dx="-0.25em" dy=".35em" fill="red">13</text>
        <text x="300" y="30" dx="-1.25em" dy=".35em">63</text>
  <svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you give another example, without percentages for the position and size of the rects and without wrapping it in another svg element, please?

Comment: Thank you very much!